# python: set one function to take the same arguments as another

Tags: python

I have a class with a member that is a list of another class. So I want something like

```
class primary_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.slist = []
    def add_secondary_class(self, <arguments>):
        self.slist.append(secondary_class(<arguments>))
```

Basically I want to be able to pass add_secondary_class arguments the exact same way I would pass them to the secondary_class constructor.

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` are way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Also, `*args` and `**kwargs` are very useful here

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42471083/1222951).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def add_secondary_class(self, *args):
    self.slist.append(secondary_class(*args))
```

or, if you have kwargs

```
def add_secondary_class(self, **kwargs):
    self.slist.append(secondary_class(**kwargs))
```

Comment: Alas this doesn't do it. Using `**kwargs`, I end up with
`TypeError: add_secondary_class() takes exactly 1 argument (8 given)`

Comment: how did you call the function `add_secondary_class()`?

Comment: `a = primary_class();
a.add_secondary_class(<args>)`

Comment: with `kwargs` (keyword arguments) you need to call them as such `foo(bar=5, bar2='param2', bar3=[])`, i.e. with keywords

Comment: Woops. Overlooked that I was adding some without keywords and some with. `def add_secondary_class(self,*args,**kwargs):` works perfectly. Thanks.